# How can i solve this issue error during template rendering rendering django?

Tags: python, django

**Error during template rendering in django**
I'm trying to run the server but it always shows this error. How can i solve this issue.

In my item_list.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Here is the list of items.</h1>
    
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

In base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>merobooks</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    {% block body %}
    
    {% endblock %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Item

def item_list(request):
    context = {
        'items': Item.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'main/item_list.html', context)
```

In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.item_list, name='item-list')
]
```

This shows the following error

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "main_item" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d", "main_item"."title", "main_item"."price" FROM "main_item...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "main_item" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d", "main_item"."title", "main_item"."price" FROM "main_item...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: C:\Users\keskh\.virtualenvs\merobooks-K3uFXFWX\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  C:\Users\keskh\.virtualenvs\merobooks-K3uFXFWX\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\keskh\\Desktop\\Python\\dev\\djangoDev\\merobooks',
 'C:\\Users\\keskh\\.virtualenvs\\merobooks-K3uFXFWX\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\users\\keskh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\keskh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\keskh\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\keskh\\.virtualenvs\\merobooks-K3uFXFWX',
 'C:\\Users\\keskh\\.virtualenvs\\merobooks-K3uFXFWX\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 31 Jul 2020 01:37:34 +0000

relation "main_item" does not exist LINE 1: ...d", "main_item"."title", "main_item"."price" FROM "main_item... ^
```

I'm trying to run the server but it doesn't work. Always shows above error. How can i solve this issue.
help needed

Comment: what's your models.py like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave this as a comment but my reputation apparently is too low.

From the error it looks like the `main_item` table does not exist in your database. Maybe you haven't performed your migrations?

Try running this:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and spent a lot of time checking the files for typos and other issues, to perform the migrations is pretty obvious still easily forgotten.

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate 
manage.py runserver
```

fixed the issue for me, well done!